# How to register JS engine in asp.core MVC React application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The following service will show an error. `missing using reference`

```
services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => options.DefaultEngineName = ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName)
                    .AddChakraCore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the following `NuGet` Packages

> JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore
>
> JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Extensions.MsDependencyInjection
>
> JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core

Then attach the following in `starup.cs`

```
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Extensions.MsDependencyInjection;
```